# Why is laravel changing the name of the column?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

**Here is the error I received:**

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name '**user_user_id**'. (SQL: insert into [APPLICATIONS] ([app_nm], [app_path], [app_readme_path], [app_manual_path], [is_url], [user_user_id]) values (TEST, uploads/2240120001.jpg, uploads/50225114.5-Data.pdf, uploads/9275171481557696855-FixedDeposits.docx, 0, 1))"

**I have 3 Models:**

**User.php**

```
public $primaryKey = 'user_id';

public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role','USER_ROLE','user_id','role_id');
}
```

**Role.php**

```
public $timestamps = false;
public $primaryKey = 'role_id';

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'APPLICATIONS';
protected $primaryKey='app_id';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Laravel adds 'user_' to the 'user_id' column name resulting in the above error.
I have checked the laravel 5.5 api to see if there is an additional parameter that needs to be supplied but that doesn't seem to be the case.

What would cause this concatenation and how do I fix it?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined the user relationship on Post properly. By default, if you don't explicitly add the related tables, Eloquent will infer the name of the foreign key field from the table name, and the primary key name.

In your case, the relationship table name is *user* and the primary key of that table you have defined as *user_id*. Because of this, it assumes the foreign key in your APPLICATIONS table to be *user_user_id*.

To address this, explicity name your foreign and other table ids in your relationship:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'user_id');
}
```

The second parameter in the above code will be your foreign key on the APPLICATIONS table (since you haven't explicitly said what is meant to be)